# Failed to initialise SD card on Leonardo

Tags: arduino-leonardo, sd-card, arduino-pro-micro

I'm trying to connect SD card reader to my Arduino. For testing i'm running [CardInfo](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/CardInfo) example.

It seems like it runs ok when I'm running it on my Arduino UNO, but it fails to initialise SD Card while i'm running it on any Arduino with Atmega32U4 chip. I tried on two Leonardo's and Micro Pro.

This is my pinout:

```
CardReader       Arduino    

CS          <->     4
SCK         <->    13
MISO        <->    12
MOSI        <->    11
VCC         <->    5V 
GND         <->    GND
```

I'm using Library in version 1.2.1 if that's make difference.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Leonardo has the SPI pins on the ICSP header, not on pins 11, 12, 13.

[image: Leonardo pinout]

And a Pro Micro has the SPI pins on 14, 15, 16.

[image: Pro Micro pinout]

Comment: I remember i used different pins on pro micro, but i really thought i used exactly same on Leonardo and Uno. I bit panicked after suddenly my card stopped working on both boards.